# How to prevent Corda Service auto-initialisation in MockNetwork flow tests?

Tags: corda

As of Corda 2.0, constructors of classes annotated with `@CordaService` are automatically invoked during node start. Corda Service original class implementations may, for example, initialise network connections in their constructors, which may not be desirable in unit tests.

My current workaround is to use a boolean flag (set from an environment variable) that marks whether to run or skip Corda Service initialisation code. Is there a better way to do this (e.g. inject a mock Corda Service class instance into `MockNetwork.MockNode` without using PowerMock and the like)?

Answer (score 0):

Your workaround is currently the best way to handle this. See https://r3-cev.atlassian.net/browse/CORDA-989.

In your approach, you might define your service as follows:

```
@CordaService
class MyService(services: ServiceHub) : SingletonSerializeAsToken()  {
    private companion object {
        val logger = loggerFor<MyService>()
        val load = System.getenv("enable-my-service")
    }

    init {
        if (load == "false") {
            logger.warn("Not loading service")
        } else {
            logger.info("Loading service")
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can toggle your service off in tests using an environment variable.